# Subquery in PowerBI

Tags: sql, subquery, powerbi

I'm trying to do this subquery in PowerBI

```
select 
Date,
sum(SalesVolume)
from table
WHERE Year = 2017 and Month = 1 
AND BusinessID in (select BusinessId from [table]
WHERE Year = 2017 and month= 1 
    AND Category= 'ALL IN ONE' and Values = 'DE 70 A 100 GR.' group by 
    BusinessID)
Group by Date
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And where is the outermost `GROUP BY Date`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part, already edited

Answer (score 0):

In the Query Editor, I would duplicate the **table** Query, and call it **table - BusinessID ALL IN ONE**.  In that new Query I would apply the filters required to **Category** and **Values**.

Then, back in the **table** Query, I would add a Merge step, selecting the new Query.  I would select the **Year** and **month** columns from both Queries for matching. I would then add a step to Expand the added column - I would extract the **Category** column and rename it e.g. **Business has All in one transcations**.

You could then use that new column as a Slicer or Filter in the Report view.

The Group By and Sum are regular behaviours in the Report view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write this with an EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT Date, SUM(SalesVolume)
FROM table t
WHERE Year = 2017
AND Month = 1 
AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM [table] t2
 WHERE Year = 2017
 AND Month= 1
 AND Category= 'ALL IN ONE'
 AND Values = 'DE 70 A 100 GR.'
 AND t.BusinessID = t2.BusinessID)
Group by Date
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved it. In DAX is : CALCULATE(SUM(table[SalesVolume]),FILTER(ALL(table[CodigoNegocio]),table[SalesVolume])